# paypal buy button

Tags: php, paypal

Я использую кнопку для сбора денег paypal buy button. Когда человек оплачивает покупку его переносит на страницу где пишут что мол все хорошо и нажмите ссылку для возврата на сайт продавца. После нажатия его должно перенести на мою страницу со скриптом success.php где в базу данных записывается информация о новом платеже. Все хорошо и работало, но сегодня получилась такая ситуация, что человек не нажал этой ссылки и закрыл страницу. Как предотвратить такие ситуации?

Comment: У них же есть back-end integration, при помощи которого и надо узнавать о платежах. Т.е. вам надо нормально интегрировать платежку

Comment: Весёлый способ)))
Используй апи. [Здесь почитай](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128198)

Answer (score 1):

В рамках той схемы что вы используете - никак. Можно получать [уведомления IPN](https://www.paypal.com/ru/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside) от PayPal, но для этого вам нужно сделать обработку этих данных, собственно все расписано на странице документации. Могу предположить что для этого вам потребуется и другую логику сайта существенно переработать.

В связи с этим думаю быстрым "решением" будет просто добавить просьбу обязательно нажимать кнопку перехода с PayPal чтобы платеж был обработан быстрее. Ну и занятся переходом на IPN.